# ASP.NET Web Api join two tables to make an array of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

This might be already asked question but I still can't solve my problem. I don't even know if I am on the right path. Some help will be appreciated.

I have two model classes in an ASP.NET Web API project looking like this:

```
namespace Artists.Models
{
    public class Artist
    {
        public int ArtistID { get; set; }
        public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and :

```
namespace Artists.Models
{
    public class Project
    {
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public int ArtistID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

That created two SQL tables connected by `ArtistID` as a foreign key in `Project`.

I have this controller code:

```
public IQueryable<Object> GetArtists()
{
     return from a in db.Artists
            join p in db.Projects on a.ArtistID equals p.ArtistID
            select new
            {
                account_name = a.ArtistName,
                project_name = p.ProjectName
            };
}
```

that returns this output in Postman:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Jack",
        "project_name": "ProjectOne"
    },
    {
        "name": "Mike",
        "project_name": "ProjectTwo"
    },
    {
        "name": "Mike",
        "project_name": "ProjectThree"
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "project_name": "ProjectFour"
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "project_name": "ProjectFive"
    }
]
```

but I want the output to be like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Jack",
        "projects": ["ProjectOne"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Mike",
        "projects": ["ProjectTwo", "ProjectThree"]
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "projects": ["ProjectFour", "ProjectFive"]
    },
]
```

Am I even close? I know this might an asked question but I really can't figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Query syntax

If you want to keep using **query syntax** you can join into collection and then project its results to only return `ProjectName` from `artistProjects`, ie:

```
public IQueryable<Object> GetArtists()
{

    return from a in db.Artists
            join p in db.Projects on a.ArtistID equals p.ArtistID into artistProjects
            select new
            {
                name = a.ArtistName,
                projects = artistProjects.Select(ap => ap.ProjectName)
            };

}
```

---

### Method syntax

If you want to go for **method syntax** then read below.
You could add navigation property to Artist, ie:

```
namespace Artists.Models
{
    public class Artist
    {
        public int ArtistID { get; set; }
        public string ArtistName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then modify your query to eager load (join) `Projects` for `Artist`:

```
public IQueryable<Object> GetArtists()
{
    return db.Artists
            .Include(a => a.Projects)
            .Select(a => 
                new
                {
                    name = a.ArtistName,
                    projects = a.Projects.Select(p => p.ProjectName)
                });
}
```

Comment: Dude I can't thank you enough. This has helped me a LOT. I just learn from you for the ICollection. Thank you again Sir and have a nice day.

Comment: Good luck with your journey in .NET. :)

Comment: Using the "Method syntax", when i don't use the line .Include(a => a.Projects), still everything works fine. Can i delete it or i need it for other reasons not known to me. Just out of curiosity so i will know i the future.

Comment: It means you have lazy loading enabled and it gets joined automatically when you request it. So yes, you might not need it.