# ASP.NET Core & Entity Framework Core : one-to-many relation and navigation properties

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core, and controller API for my react app database connect.

I have 4 classes `Customer`, `Product`, `Store` and `Sales`. The `Customer`, `Product` and `Store` table have a one-to-many relation with sales.

[image: Here is the image of database relation which I am trying to implement]

Sales class

```
public class Sales
{
    [Key]
    public int SalesId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public string DateSold { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Store Store { get; set; }
}
```

Customer class

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public IList<Sales> Sales { get; set; }
}
```

The other Product and store are same as customer class.

I run the migration command but the database was not created and command run successful so I created database and then I run the update-database which created all the tables in database.

If I add navigation properties to table will it fetch Sales record with Customer, Product and Store record as per ID in sales record.

I want to fetch sales record and in the sales table there is customer, product and store ID. How can I fetch their record?

My tables look like this:

[image: My database diagram]

Comment: There's a couple of ways to do this, but I like using the Foreign Key which will tie the ids to the "virtual" tables:  https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx  (you should make the ints nullable... so "public int? ProductId { get; set; }")

Comment: @Dale K I do tried this [ForeignKey] on the navigation property in the dependent entity but it did not created the navigation properties. I will try the principal

Comment: @Dale K I tried [ForeignKey] on the navigation property in the dependent entity and now I have Foreign key in Sales table but not navigation properties

Comment: I think you meant to tag @pcalkins as I haven't contributed to this question.

Comment: Ohh Sorry @ pcalkins and @ Dale K

Comment: @ pcalkins  I tried [ForeignKey] on the navigation property in the dependent entity and now I have Foreign key in Sales table but not navigation properties

Comment: you don't need navigation properties... (at least I don't use them)  You'd just use LINQ queries and your virtual tables will be accessible... ex: Sales.Customer.Name..  The foreign key will be used to facilitate this.  (It's the primary key of the "Customer" record...)

Comment: ...so all you need to do is set the foreign keys when you create the Sale.

Comment: @ pcalkins I added the Foreign key in sales table and now I am getting error

Comment: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Sales_Customer_CustomerRefId". The conflict occurred in database "ASPCoreReact", table "dbo.Customer", column 'CustomerId'.

Comment: looks like a loop because of that list of Sales in Customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to fetch sales record and in the sales table there is customer, product and store ID. How can I fetch their record?

Based on your model design  , you could use [`Include`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) method for loading related data like below:

*Controller*

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<object>> GetSales() 
    {
        var salesdata = await _context.Sales
                    .Include(s => s.Customer)
                    .Include(s => s.Product)
                    .Include(s => s.Store)
                    .Select(s => new
                    {
                        salesId = s.SalesId,
                        dateSold = s.DateSold,
                        customer = new
                        {
                            name = s.Customer.Name,
                            address = s.Customer.Address
                        },
                        product = new
                        {
                            name = s.Product.Name,
                            price = s.Product.Price
                        },
                        store = new
                        {
                            name = s.Store.Name,
                            address = s.Store.Address
                        }
                    })
                    .ToListAsync();
        return salesdata; 
    }
```

For query syntax , you could use the [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators) in EF Core for Complex Query Operators

```
var data = from s in _context.Sales
                   join cu in _context.Customer on s.CustomerId equals cu.CustomerId 
                   join p in _context.Product on s.ProductId equals p.ProductId 
                   join st in _context.Store on s.StoreId equals st.StoreId 
                   select new
                   {
                       salesId = s.SalesId,
                       dateSold = s.DateSold,
                       customer = new
                       {
                           name = s.Customer.Name,
                           address = s.Customer.Address
                       },
                       product = new
                       {
                           name = s.Product.Name,
                           price = s.Product.Price
                       },
                       store = new
                       {
                           name = s.Store.Name,
                           address = s.Store.Address
                       }
                   };
        return await data.ToListAsync();
```

*Result*
[image]

Comment: I am using API controller and in get API it looks something like this

Comment: // GET: api/Sales
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Sales>>> GetSales()
        {
            return await _context.Sales.ToListAsync();
        }

Comment: I want to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004760/asp-net-web-api-join-two-tables-to-make-an-array-of-objects

Comment: @RahulWaghmare , please check my updated. If you find my workaround works , could you mark my reply as answer?

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I have marked your reply as Answer.

Comment: I have one more question, Can I fetch just all the record using single API. can i just include all customer in sales I need it for edit section.